[webpack-dev-server][HPM] Error occurred while proxying request...[ETIMEDOUT]
I'm not familiar with webpack and I'm really appriciate getting advice from you.
1.project background:
I use vercel to proxy local requests to remote cloud backend service.
here is my webpack.dev.config.js:
module.exports = merge(commonConfig, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: "eval",
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'https://fndeep-backend.vercel.app',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
                timeout: 360000,
                logLevel:'debug'
            }
        },
    },
})

2.info from console:
The app run successfully console log and 'webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in 77643 ms' finally.
3.problem:
Eventhough the project run successfully, my webpage can't be rendered completely because of the 'team' source can't be loaded:error message from browser devtools 
and then got error message from my IDE console:as shown
I also used Postman to send request 'GET https://fndeep-backend.vercel.app/api/v1/team', it worked well and got responds as expected.
So what should I do to fix this bug or did I miss something to config it properly? Thanks for your time.
